# CSS apply a class "on click"

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like the class "animated fadeOutDown" to be applied to mydiv "#article" when users click on `.article-close`.

I tried the below but without success. Your help would be welcome.

Many thanks.

```
<script>
$(".article-close").click(function() {
  $("#article").css("animated fadeOutDown");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you type your question title into Google before asking it?

Comment: Actually incredible our dear Goog did not yield you and results `:)`

Comment: What jquery version are using? try this `$(".article-close").on('click', function() {` or `$(document).on('click', '.article-close', function() {`

Comment: First link on google, searching for the exact title (copy-pasted): http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11841/add-a-class-on-click-event/p1 . So I think the OP did not google it. @Zenith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".article-close").click(function() {
  $("#article").addClass("animated fadeOutDown");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
Actually spend more time here: http://api.jquery.com and learn them all! will be useful at any time, you don't need to know exactly every method or selector, but at least you'll know what you can do with jQuery and you can always go back to the API for what you need. 
Also you can find very useful jQuery cheatSheets on Goog, print those pages and attach on the wall :)

I like this one: http://oscarotero.com/jquery/ but there are some with a short explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong.You have to use [**addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

```
$(".article-close").click(function() {
  $("#article").addClass("animated fadeOutDown");
});
```

The     **[css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** is used to  set or return one or more style **properties** for the selected elements.